# The %d operator isn't working in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

The operator %d seems to work fine here

```
print("The value in 10 years is $%d. Don't spend it all in one place!") % (principal)

main()
```

However,  it does not work here:

```
 x = int(input("Enter how many years you would to calculate the future value of $%d. \nPlease choose at least 10 years: " ))  % principal
```

Here's the full code:

```
def main():
    #Describes the program
    print("This program calculates the future value")
    print("of a 10-year investment.")

    #Prompts the user to enter a principal amount
    principal = int(input("Enter the initial principal: "))

    x = int(input("Enter how many years you would to calculate the future value of $%d. \nPlease choose at least 10 years: " ))  % principal
    #loops through 10 periods, years in this case
    for i in range( x ):
        #calculates the new principal based on the interest
        principal = principal * (1 + 0.75)

     #prints the value and %d is a placeholder to format the integer
    print("The value in 10 years is $%d. Don't spend it all in one place!") % (principal)
    main()
```

Is there a scope of this operator that I'm missing, or is it just used incorrectly and should be formatted completely different?

Comment: You are applying the `%` operator to the return value of `int()`; integers don't support string formatting, the normal function of the `%` operator (modulus) is applied instead: `10 % 5` is `0`, `10 % 4` is 2, etc.

Comment: Also, your first claim is wrong; `print()` returns `None`, so `print('...') % (something,)` raises an exception. You'd have to apply it to the string *before* printing.

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3? If that `print` line actually worked, you'd have to be on Python 2.

Comment: You want `print("hello %s" % name)`, not `print("hello %s") % name`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is incorrect:

```
x = int(input("Enter how many years you would to calculate the future value of $%d. \nPlease choose at least 10 years: " ))  % principal
```

Your should replace it by:

```
x = int(input("Enter how many years you would to calculate the future value of $%d. \nPlease choose at least 10 years: " % principal))
```

Or using `format()`:

```
x = int(input("Enter how many years you would to calculate the future value of ${}. \nPlease choose at least 10 years: ".format(principal)))
```

Also, this code is incorrect too:

```
print("The value in 10 years is $%d. Don't spend it all in one place!") % (principal)
```

You can replace it by:

```
print("The value in 10 years is $%d. Don't spend it all in one place!" % principal)
```

Or using `format()`:

```
print("The value in 10 years is ${}. Don't spend it all in one place!".format(principal))
```

**NB:**

`%d` will format your `principal` variable into an `integer = int`
You could use `%f` and format it into a `float` for better representation.

Comment: The same applies to the `print()` function call at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
print("The value in 10 years is $" + str(principal) + ". Don't spend it all in one place!")
```

and don't forget to move your call main() outside of your function definition.

Comment: There are better ways of formatting a string. The OP was roughly on the right track, just confused as to where to apply the `%` operator. Still, `str.format()` would be better still.

Comment: @DYZ I'm also a beginner. I didn't know about str.format(). it does seem to be better.